# What could cause CentOS not to install on certain hardware?

Tags: linux, installation, centos

I'm working on some various robotic platforms and I'm attempting to put CentOS 7 (Atomic Host) on all of them.  The last 3 have worked without issues, but on this platform, it's using a PC/104 stack and uses a breakout cable for VGA & USB ports.  I get the media menu where I choose to "Install", "Test Media & Install" or "Quit".  When I choose "Install", the process hangs and stays in a black screen.  My longest wait has been ~20 minutes.  On all other platforms, it's no more than a minute until the menu comes up.

Is this platform unfortunately just 'unsupported' hardware for CentOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://grokbase.com/t/centos/centos/147j2asjpp/anyone-using-centos-6-on-pc104-stacks

This might give you the proper information.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried another installation disc and it gave an error for installing a 64 bit OS onto a 32 bit CPU (i868).  I didn't realize that this was a 32 bit machine but because I'm using CentOS Atomic Host 7 (and it's 64 bit only), I'm going to just put that platform on hiatus.